# TypeError: binding.value is not a function Vue js v-click-outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i am using v-click-outside and want to pass value to the function but i am having error

[image]

[image]

This is how i am passing a value
[image]

Here is my code from Main.js file

```
vue_app.directive('click-outside', {
    beforeMount(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.clickOutsideEvent = evt => {
            evt.stopPropagation()
            if (!(el === evt.target || el.contains(evt.target))) {
                binding.value(evt, el)
            }
        }
        // Wait 1 frame otherwise a potential click that mounted the element will immediately trigger a click-outside event:
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            document.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
        })
    },
    unmounted(el) {
        document.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a function to the directive, but right now you call it right away and pass the returned value. So instead of

```
v-click-outside="hideAllShowDetailDropdown(show.show_ID)"
```

Try this:

```
v-click-outside="() => hideAllShowDetailDropdown(show.show_ID)"
```